# Is there any way to add float number to millisecond in java Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

In java Calendar class while adding milliseconds I am missing the decimal precession.  Since method expects integer

For example: 
1000/12 = 83.333333

In java
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, **(integer)**);

Which takes only 83 and .33333 is missed.

**Does anybody know how to handle this scenario in java ?**

Comment: And what should the decimal value represent then? Nanoseconds?

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Calendar` keeps time information at the level of milliseconds,

> An instant in time can be represented by a millisecond value that is an offset from the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian).

`java.time.LocalDateTime` has a sensitivity in the level of nanosecond.

> Time is represented to nanosecond precision. For example, the value
>   "2nd October 2007 at 13:45.30.123456789" can be stored in a
>   LocalDateTime.

so if you need microsecond or nanosecond level information, you can not use `java.util.Calendar`, and you should use `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Comment: For actual moments use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`. The `LocalDateTime` class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC and so does *not* represent specific point on the timeline.